# Why string is not printing correctly?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring, stored-procedures

I have created a user type in oracle

```
create or replace type my_friend_list 
is
table of 
varchar2(100);
```

Now i have written a procedure which has a output parameter like this :

```
  PROCEDURE friends_diff_prc
  (
   my_name IN VARCHAR2,
   friend_i   IN my_friend_list ,
   good_friend_o   OUT my_friend_list ,
   best_friend_o   OUT my_friend_list ,
   isSuccess         OUT NUMBER 
  );
```

I run it on `SQLDeveloper` And it is running correctly .

And it is giving me list both of my good friends and best friends.

But when i am calling it through JAVA Class which is extending `StoredProcedure`.

`best_friend` list is correcly coming but for the `good_friend` list it is printing

```
Ljava.lang.Object;@24342434, 
Ljava.lang.Object;@243a243a,
Ljava.lang.Object;@24402440,
Ljava.lang.Object;@24462446
```

My java code to fetch this output arraylist is like this:

```
List<String> goodfriends = Arrays.asList((String[]) results.get("good_friend_o");
List<String> bestfriends = Arrays.asList((String[]) results.get("best_friend_o");
```

Why it is not giving correct result for good_friends ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Ljava.lang.Object;@24462446` means that you're trying to print a `Object[]` array. Could you try to go through a `good_friend` instance using `for(Object o : (Object[]) goodFriend) {System.out.println(o);}` and edit your question with the result?

Comment: @sp00M I am not able to get why it is printing correctly for bestfriends

Comment: I don't know too, but maybe we'll find if your try to print as I told you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Getting the answer as Array of String, and then storing in a String of List.. You cannot store the String[] into String straightly.

can you post the, java code for fetching and printing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will print the strings

```
System.out.println("Printing goodfriends");
for (Object object : goodfriends) {
    Object[] goodfriendsString = (Object[]) object;
    for (Object object2 : objLocationVO) {
    System.out.println(object2);            
     }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a solution but a debbuging step. So, it should be a comment rather than an anwser.